# Is there any way to access Dropbox Website using AccessToken

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am creating an app using Dropbox HTTP Service.
I have to implement photos hub in my app... like https://www.dropbox.com/photos

But there is no api to do the same, so i am creating an in-app browser and then will navigate to https://www.dropbox.com/photos.

But the problem is even i have the accesstoken for the account i have to again login in the browser, is there any way i can by-pass the login by using the previous accesstoken that is already being used by my whole app...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there is no way to log the user into the Dropbox website using an authentication token from the API.